# Gathering outputs from an MSBuild exec task

Tags: msbuild

I have a batch script that I want to call from an MSBuild project, and [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) says I can't use output from the batch (either console / environment variables) in the MSBuild project.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I ended up writing a custom MSBuild task that does what I want and return the output.

Comment: This link could be useful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/tfsbuild/thread/ef1a0e09-ef66-4ddf-947b-149311182b43

Comment: Could you post your custom MDBuild task that solved your issue please?

Comment: @StuHarper - don't have the code anymore, it was about 3 companies ago.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16804205/1990221) shows how to do this without redirecting to a file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the command to a file using "> output.txt" and read that into a variable.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <OutputFile>$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\Output.txt</OutputFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<Exec Command="dir > &quot;$(OutputFile)&quot;" />
<ReadLinesFromFile File="$(OutputFile)">
   <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="OutputLines"/>
</ReadLinesFromFile>
<Message Text="@(OutputLines->'%(Identity)', '%0a%0d')" />
```

Comment: this looks very hacky, why should a file be written if the output of the command is just useful for the MSBuild logic? Then you have to delete the file later...

Comment: Builds that use logic like this become painful to manage but I'd rather it be working and ugly than not working at all.

Comment: While I agree it is a bit sloppy, it is not that big of a deal to add the MSBuild line <Delete Files="$(OutputFile)"/> immediately after checking its contents so there are no stay files lying around.

Comment: FYI. A modern way it is mentioned in [How get exec task output with msbuild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938679/how-get-exec-task-output-with-msbuild)

Comment: @GonzaloContento probably wanted to link [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804205/177710) directly 