# Running Python script to deploy from MSBuild

Tags: python-2.7, deployment, msbuild

I have a python script that is doing some deployment.
I want to run that script from msbuild and get the output in case it pass, or failed.
So, how can I communicate to msbuild of the status , and the error text?
I want to show the result on the build server.
I have to use python 2.7, and cannot use 3.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the command using the Exec task and [capture it's output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519177/gathering-outputs-from-an-msbuild-exec-task). For example:

```
<Target Name="GetPythonOutput">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PyCommand>/path/to/python.exe -a /path/to/pthonfile</PyCommand>
    <TempFile>ExecTempFile</TempFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Exec Command="$(PyCommand) &gt; $(TempFile)" />

  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(TempFile)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="PyOutput"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <Delete Files="$(TempFile)" />

  <Message Text="Python command output was: @(PyOutput)" />
</Target>
```

If you are using .Net 4.5 things are better since `Exec` [can do most of the work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938679/how-get-exec-task-output-with-msbuild#16804205)