# How to solve error MSB6003 when compile vs2015 project with platform set vs2013(v120)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

error MSB6003: The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. The working directory "mkl\tools" does not exist".

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a User Macro in a property sheet for MKLProductDir, or create an environment variable *MKLProductDir*.

Let's say this is the pathname to your installation of the Intel MKL:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows\mkl
```

You need to either:

**1. Create a new environment variable**

```
right click start -> System -> Advanced System Settings
Environment variables
```

add a new environment variable:

```
MKLProductDir        C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows
```

**2. Add a User Macro to a property sheet in Visual Studio (here, Visual Studio 2015)**

```
Open your solution 
In the Solution Explorer (right window), look at the bottom tabs - click on Property Manager
```

You should see properties for Debug | Win32 , Debug | x64 , Release | Win32 , Release x64. You could edit any of the property sheets in the items listed under each section. Consider creating a [custom property sheet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810603/in-visual-studio-projects-can-a-user-macro-be-set-across-multiple-configuration)

```
Open up a property sheet (right-click, Properties).
Left side - under Common Properties - you will see User Macros
Click on User Macros
Add Macro
MKLProductDir        C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows
```

Save your solution.

See this Intel Forum post, [Intel Composer 2016 Update 3 + VS2015](https://software.intel.com/zh-cn/comment/1891027) for a little bit more information on the issue.