# MSBuild: How do I CopyFiles to DestinationFolder that is determined by output of executing a command?

Tags: git, msbuild, githooks, msbuild-task

I need to copy a specific git hook file into the local repo on MSBuild to enforce some client side validation which work fine in general, however, I noticed there are exceptional cases where worktrees are setup slightly different from the suggested config. This can be get around if the `DestPath` below is acquire when the task is being execute from `git rev-parse --git-path hooks`.

```
<Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(HookFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="$(DestPath)" 
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True"
/>
```

My guess is to add an Exec task in front of Copy to collect the variable but I am not sure how to make the output available in the Copy task.

```
<Exec Command="git rev-parse --git-path hooks"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to answer in [Gathering outputs from an MSBuild exec task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3499234/672441) and I managed to handle it by executing the command and redirect the output to a text file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <OutputFile>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)temp.txt</OutputFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<Exec Command="git rev-parse --path-format=absolute --git-path hooks > &quot;$(OutputFile)&quot;" />
```

Then read the value from the text file.

```
<ReadLinesFromFile File="$(OutputFile)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="OutputLines"/>
</ReadLinesFromFile>
```

And substitute back to the task.

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(GitHookFiles)"
      DestinationFolder="@(OutputLines)" 
      OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True"
/>
```

And finally clean up the file.

```
<Delete Files="$(OutputFile)" />
```